# how "Continuous control with Gaussian policies" are compute?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient

in [blog](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/rl-policy-gradients-explained-9b13b688b146) about Reinforcement learning in part, they discuss "Continuous control with Gaussian policies" Hui define the values for actions as Gaussian distributed [image]. and the policy is defined using a Gaussian distribution with means computed from a deep network: [image]. I have questions about how he compute the partial derivative of the log π as: [image] and then how backpropagate update become [image]

Comment: what's your question? those equations just follow from the definition of the gaussian density

Comment: @shimao  thanks for comment as mention my question is how backpropagate update become as mention as above

Comment: it sounds like the math is giving you trouble. please point out exactly what you don't understand about the derivation of the update.

Comment: thanks what happen to the df/dθ?